# Ruby + Nginx/Passenger (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

can I have advice on issue during app migration.
I'm not familiar with rails and got this legacy app. I checked code and did not found any method **X**. And I know that 2.0.0 is really outdated. Unfortunately, Googling/reading Stackoverflow did not helped.

P.S. Sorry if this is simple and obvious rails question.

Trace:

```html
App 24947 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: undefined method `x' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000003801828> (NoMethodError)
App 24947 output:     /opt/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing'
App 24947 output:     /opt/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/webpacker-0.1/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:12:in `block in <class:Engine>'
App 24947 output:     /opt/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
App 24947 output:     /opt/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
App 24947 output:     /opt/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
App 24947 output:     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
App 24947 output:     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
App 24947 output:     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
App 24947 output:     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
App 24947 output:     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
App 24947 output:     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
App 24947 output:     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
App 24947 output:     /opt/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
App 24947 output:     /opt/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
App 24947 output:     /opt/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
App 24947 output:     /opt/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
App 24947 output:     config.ru:3:in `require'
App 24947 output:     config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
App 24947 output:     /opt/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
App 24947 output:     /opt/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
App 24947 output:     config.ru:1:in `new'
App 24947 output:     config.ru:1:in `<main>'
App 24947 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
App 24947 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
App 24947 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
App 24947 output:     /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
App 24947 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
App 24947 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 24947 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

config/application.rb

```html
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module SubAccountEnrollments
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
              'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
    }
  end
end
```

bundle env:

````html
## Environment

```
Bundler             1.17.3
  Platforms         ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby                2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path         /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  Config Dir        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/etc
RubyGems            3.0.8
  Gem Home          /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
  Gem Path          /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global
  User Path         /root/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  Bin Dir           /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
Tools               
  Git               1.8.3.1
  RVM               1.29.9 (latest)
  rbenv             not installed
  chruby            not installed
  rubygems-bundler  (1.4.5)
```

## Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2020-02-18
Git SHA           d7089abb6a
Released Version  false
```

## Bundler settings

```
git.allow_insecure
  Set for the current user (/root/.bundle/config): "true"
frozen
  Set for your local app (/opt/.bundle/config): true
path
  Set for your local app (/opt/.bundle/config): "vendor/bundle"
without
  Set for your local app (/opt/.bundle/config): [:development, :test]
```

## Gemfile

### Gemfile

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'coalescing_panda'
gem 'open_uri_redirections'
gem 'rubyzip', '1.3.0'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'activesupport'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '3.1.3'
  gem 'webmock'
end

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'mysql2',  '~> 0.3.18'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

### Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.1)
      activemodel (= 4.0.1)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.4)
    activesupport (4.0.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    arel (4.0.2)
    bearcat (1.0.21)
      footrest (>= 0.2.2)
    builder (3.1.4)
    coalescing_panda (4.0.5)
      bearcat (= 1.0.21)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
      delayed_job_active_record
      haml-rails
      ims-lti
      jquery-rails
      macaddr (= 1.6.1)
      p3p
      rails (~> 4.0.1)
      sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
      useragent
    coderay (1.1.3)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.7)
    crack (0.4.4)
    debugger (1.6.8)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.3.5)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.8)
    delayed_job (4.1.9)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 6.2)
    delayed_job_active_record (4.1.5)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 6.2)
      delayed_job (>= 3.0, < 5)
    diff-lcs (1.4.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faraday (0.17.3)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    footrest (0.5.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      faraday (>= 0.9.0, < 1)
      link_header (>= 0.0.7)
    haml (5.2.1)
      temple (>= 0.8.0)
      tilt
    haml-rails (1.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.1)
      haml (>= 4.0.6, < 6.0)
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.1)
    hashdiff (1.0.1)
    hike (1.2.3)
    html2haml (2.2.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      haml (>= 4.0, < 6)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.5)
    i18n (0.9.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    ims-lti (1.2.4)
      builder (>= 1.0, < 4.0)
      oauth (>= 0.4.5, < 0.6)
    jbuilder (1.5.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2.0)
    jquery-rails (3.1.5)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    kgio (2.11.3)
    link_header (0.0.8)
    macaddr (1.6.1)
      systemu (~> 2.5.0)
    mail (2.5.5)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multipart-post (2.1.1)
    mysql2 (0.3.21)
    nokogiri (1.6.8.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
    oauth (0.5.4)
    open_uri_redirections (0.2.1)
    p3p (1.2.0)
      rack
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    protected_attributes (1.1.4)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.1, < 5.0)
    pry (0.13.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    public_suffix (2.0.5)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      activerecord (= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.1)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.19.1)
    rake (12.3.3)
    rdoc (5.1.0)
    rspec-core (3.0.4)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.0.4)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.0.4)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-rails (3.0.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.0.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.0.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.0.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-support (3.0.4)
    ruby_parser (3.14.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.9)
    rubyzip (1.3.0)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.5)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 3.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sdoc (2.0.3)
      rdoc (>= 5.0)
    sexp_processor (4.14.0)
    shoulda-matchers (3.1.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
    sprockets (2.12.5)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.13)
    systemu (2.5.2)
    temple (0.8.2)
    thor (1.0.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.58)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unicorn (5.7.0)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    useragent (0.16.10)
    webmock (3.10.0)
      addressable (>= 2.3.6)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
      hashdiff (>= 0.4.0, < 2.0.0)
    webpacker (0.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activesupport
  coalescing_panda
  debugger
  jbuilder (~> 1.2)
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.18)
  open_uri_redirections
  protected_attributes
  pry
  rails (= 4.0.1)
  rails_12factor
  rspec-rails (~> 3.0.0.beta)
  rubyzip (= 1.3.0)
  sdoc
  shoulda-matchers (= 3.1.3)
  sqlite3 (~> 1.3.6)
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  unicorn
  webmock
  webpacker

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.0.0p247

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
````

Comment: Something in your code is calling `x` perhaps inadvertently, maybe even a typo where someone typed `x` and saved by accident.

Comment: I thought the same, I even used grep to get all Xs (Yeah this is sounds stupid) and I can not see any X. There is a way at least to know the file?

Comment: Did this just start happening recently? If so, what changed?